# $\sup(\sup) \leq 2 \inf(\sup)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a function $ F : [a; b] \times [a; b] \longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $F(x; y) = F(y; x)$ and $F(x; y) \leq F(x; z) +
F(z; y)$ for all $x, y, z \in [a; b].$ Prove that
$$ \sup_{x \in [a,b]}(\sup_{y \in [a,b]}F(x,y)) \leq 2\inf_{x \in [a,b]}(\sup_{y \in [a,b]} F(x,y)). $$

I did something like
$$\sup_{y \in [a,b]}F(x,y) \leq \sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(x,z) + \sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(y,z)$$
$$ \sup_{x \in [a,b]}(\sup_{y \in [a,b]}F(x,y)) \leq \sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(x,z) + \sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(y,z)$$
$$ \sup_{x \in [a,b]}(\sup_{y \in [a,b]}F(x,y)) \leq \inf_{x, y \in [a,b]}(\sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(x,z) + \sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(y,z))\leq \inf_{x \in [a,b]}\sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(x,z)\\ + \inf_{y\in [a,b]}\sup_{z \in [a,b]}F(y,z)$$

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: okay..i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more careful with your variables, but you essentially got the idea. It is just a matter of compatibility of supremum and infimum with inequalities.
Starting from the 'triangular inequality' you are provided:
$$\forall x,y,z,\ F(x,y)\leq F(z,x) + F(z,y)$$
Taking the supremum over $y$:
$$\forall x,z,\ \sup_y F(x,y) \leq \sup_y (F(z,x) + F(z,y))=F(z,x) + \sup_y F(z,y)$$
Taking the supremum over $x$:
$$\forall z,\ \sup_x\sup_y F(x,y) \leq \sup_x\left(F(z,x) + \sup_y F(z,y)\right) = \sup_x F(z,x) + \sup_y F(z,y)$$
The last term is equal to $2\sup_x F(z,x)$ since $x$ and $y$ are both bound variables.
That is:
$$\forall z,\ \sup_x\sup_y F(x,y) \leq 2\sup_x F(z,x)$$
Taking the infimum over $z$ gives you your inequality (with $z$ and $x$ replacing $x$ and $y$, but this is the same quantity since they are bound variables).